# Set urgent option in phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

How can I sent an mail with phpmailer with the option urgent set like in MS Outlook?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is done by adding importance and priority headers to the outbound email.  MS Outlook uses a particular one of its own, while most other mail clients use `Importance` or `Priority`.  Add them with PHPMailer via the `AddCustomHeader()` method and the `$Priority` property.

```
// For most clients expecting the Priority header:
// 1 = High, 2 = Medium, 3 = Low
$yourMessage->Priority = 1;
// MS Outlook custom header
// May set to "Urgent" or "Highest" rather than "High"
$yourMessage->AddCustomHeader("X-MSMail-Priority: High");
// Not sure if Priority will also set the Importance header:
$yourMessage->AddCustomHeader("Importance: High");
```

Note that mail clients are free to not implement/ignore these headers, so you can't fully rely on them.  Also, many spam filters will use them as a red flag for identifying spam.  Use them with caution.

Official documentation:

[PHPMailer Properties](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#property_Priority)

[PHPMailer Methods](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_addCustomHeader)

Answer (score 1):

**Supplement:**

That work´s fine, but some SPAM Filter will use the Priority Configuration (doesn´t matters which Priority is set) to filter in SPAM.

And php Mailer will set the Priority Flag ALWAYS. (Default to 3)

So in MY php Mailer class i´d commentet the line

`$this->HeaderLine('X-Priority', $this->Priority);`

Maybe a solution like:

> class.phpmailer.php

`if($this->Priority > 0) $this->HeaderLine('X-Priority', $this->Priority);`

> And in your php script something like this:

`$yourMessage->Priority = 0;`

Makes it a bit configurable